# jQuery-Validation-Engine -- Making sure fields values do not equal

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

I'm using [jQuery-Validation-Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) to do some client side checking before sending a form to the server.

I know you can check to make sure two fields match using `validate[equals[fieldId]]` where `fieldId` is the id of the field you want to match.  Useful if you want to make sure passwords match, for example.

Now I am trying to find a way to make sure fields *don't* match.  For example, if I wanted to make sure a password field did not match a username field.

Has anyone been able to get this to work?  Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and trial and error, I answered my own question.  I'll post what I did here so others who need to do the same thing will have a reference.

Turns out you need to create a new [custom function](http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#validators/custom-function_name) in much the same way you add a [custom regex](http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#validators/custom-regex_name).  How to apply a custom regex is fairly well documented, but there's not much on how to implement a custom function (without calling a 3rd party function).

Digging around in the language file gives a better idea of how to handle it.

I had to create a custom validator with a function attached inside the language file (in this case jquery.validationEngine-en.js):

```
"notEqual":  {
    "func": function(field, rules, i, options){
        return (field.val() == $('#username').val()) ? false : true;
    },
    "alertText": "* Username and password must be different"
},
```

In my html markup, I use it like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="yourPassword" id="username"/>
<input class="validate[custom[notEqual]]" type="password" name="confirmPassword" value=""/>
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. You can also do this using funcCall.

In your case the HTML is:

```
<input class="validate[funcCall[notEqual]]" type="password" name="confirmPassword" value="">
```

and the function is:

```
function notEqual(field){
    if(field.val() == $('#username').val()){
        return "* Username and password must be different";
    }
}
```

This might be useful for times when you have validation functions that can be re-used from other libraries or other areas of your code.

http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#validators/funccall-methodname